# Download big parquet files are corrupted

Tags: python-3.x, parquet, shutil

I'm trying to download some parquet files of 1GB each. I'm using the following code

```
import shutil
import requests

def download_file(url, filename):
    with requests.get(url,  stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()

        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            f.close()

download_file("https://myfile_from_source.parquet", "myfile.parquet")
```

Most of the files are downloaded correctly but some of them are probably corrupted that we are not able to read those in spark. We get the following error while reading

```
An error occurred while calling o195.count. s3://bucket/myfile_from_source.parquet is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [22, 16, 43, 0]
```

The files are downloaded fine and there are no errors while downloading. But it only throws error while reading the files. Am I downloading the file incorrectly? I'm also running the code in AWS Glue so I'm assuming there are no network issues that can cause problems while downloading. And also it's not a one time issue but it happens quite often.

Comment: Parquet "magic numbers" are a string "PAR1", located at the beginning and at the end of a file. Can you successfully read the files back NOT from Spark?

Comment: When I open it using pandas I get `OSError: Could not open parquet input source 's3://bucket/myfile_from_source.parquet': Invalid: Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.`

Comment: have you tried to download the file with `wget` and see if you can open it locally?

Comment: Asking the obvious here, but I think what @mazaneicha is getting at is - are you sure the file is not corrupted and that it is a parquet file? If either of those are the case I’m not sure we can help.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado The file is itself not corrupted. But I do observe that this happened  when we try to download large files (>1GB). BTW I could not reproduce this problem in my local system

Comment: Can you include the code you’re using to read the data and the full traceback? Also have you tried using [s3fs](https://github.com/fsspec/s3fs)? You should be able to read the data directly from s3 using pandas/dask using a filepath prefixed with `s3://`